# How to replace return value of a service using spyOn?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

There is the following service:

```
export class CounterService {
  random: any = {
    value: 123,
    date: 456,
  };
 
  getRandom() {
    return this.random;
  }
}
```

Some component uses this service. In this component, the variable 'random' is assigned a value from the service:

```
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {
  random: any;
 
  constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {}
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.random = this.counterService.getRandom();
  }
}
```

I try to test it using the following unit-test:

```
it('should fill random', () => {
  const random = {
    value: 123456,
    date: 123456,
  };
  spy = spyOn(counterService, 'getRandom').and.returnValue(random);
  expect(component.random).toEqual(random);
});
```

However i get the following error message:

> Expected $.value = 123 to equal 123456. Expected $.date = 456 to equal
> 123456.

Could you help me fix this unit-test please?

Comment: The numbers from the service and the test are not the same... Why would you expect them to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnInit gets called when initializing.

If you want to test the operation inside `ngOnInit` method, you need to mock the service before initializing the component or manually trigger ngOnInit one more time.

Comment: But spyOn() is intended to spoof the response

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. your problem is you need to run component.ngOnInit. Just add `component.ngOnInit()` before `expect(component.random).toEqual(random);`